# Can I access metadata from a third-party GitHub repo from a Jekyll site on github-pages?

Tags: github, repository, metadata, jekyll

[It is possible to access repository metadata from a Jekyll site hosted in a `gh-pages` branch on GitHub](https://help.github.com/articles/repository-metadata-on-github-pages/).

I am now building a site where it'd help enormously if I had access to the metadata of another (of my) repositories (here called a *third-party* repository because technically it is that).

Is there any way I can set up Jekyll so that I can use metadata from that third-party repo? I.e., make Jekyll able to use metadata from two repositories rather than just the local `{{ site.github }}` one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `liquid` tag that allows you to get `site` metadatas from an other repository.

The only way to do this is to use [GitHub API](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/) on the client side with the help of javascript libraries like [github.js](https://github.com/michael/github).

Comment: On second thought the API sprang to mind, yes. Thanks for the pointer to github.js!